# Texmaker- Hotkey for Toggling PDF Viewer

Tags: texmaker

I'm wondering if there is a hotkey to toggle the pdf viewer on/off or if there is a way to configure such a hotkey in Texmaker?

Comment: you can shut it down by pressing `esc` and normally it will pop up the next time you hit `F1`

Comment: @Rico That would depend on how your quick build is configured, wouldn't it? F7 just opens the PDF.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: right, I expected the TeXmaker to be on standard configuration

Answer (score 4):

Considering the default configuration of TeXMaker, the Hotkey for showing the PDF is <kbd>F7</kbd>. 
Unfortunately, version 4.1.1 does not provide any possibilitys to toggle the PDF Viewer by pressing a Hotkey, not even to bind one. So you have to press <kbd>PDF Viewer</kbd> in the lower left corner to toggle this view.

If you are using TeXStudio, you can press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to hide the PDF Viewer and <kbd>F7</kbd> to show it again.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Texmaker on Mac, you can set a menu bar shortcut in system preferences.

To do this, open System Preferences, Keyboard, and then Shortcuts. On the left side, select App Shortcuts. Create a new shortcut by clicking the + icon. As shown in the image, set the application to texmaker.app and for "Menu Title" enter "Pdf Viewer." Then set your keyboard shortcut. Be careful not to override any existing shortcuts.

[image: shortcut settings]